# Can we generate logDNA alerts with custom titles? I want to get the log line in the title of the alert?

Tags: alerts, logdna

the logs are as follow
"XXX abc"
"XXX xyz"
"XXX pqr"

I want to make one alert logDNA on "XXX", but I want the title of the alert to show "XXX ..." on slack or the notification channel.

Please can someone look into this in case this is possible.